# Github Pages on 1&1 domain has weird behavior

Tags: github, web-hosting

I have a 1and1 domain and web server (`kyleplo.com`), and I want to link it with my  Github Pages site (`kyleplo.github.io`). I followed the instructions on the Github Help website, and now it works on HTTP on Edge and Firefox, has security errors on HTTPS, and doesn't work at all on Chrome.

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could explain what you did in order to make it work. You can answer your own question using the button below your post. Please be as specific as possible. This way, others can benefit from your answer.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Actually, I'm not sure if it's working. It loads fine on http in Firefox and Edge, but it gives security errors on https, and doesn't work on Chrome at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the [HTTP troubleshooting steps from Github](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#https-errors) suggests that you need to [remove and re-add the domain](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-removing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/) in order to trigger HTTPS:

> It can take up to an hour for your GitHub Pages site to become available over HTTPS after you add and correctly configure your custom domain. After updating existing DNS settings, you may need to remove and re-add your custom domain to your GitHub account to trigger the process of enabling HTTPS.

By the looks of things, you've forwarded the A record correctly, but haven't taken this additional step, so the SAN entries on the certificate are just for the generic pages `www.github.com, *.github.io, *.githubusercontent.com, *.github.com, github.com, github.io, githubusercontent.com` hence the SSL error.

I would go back and double check you have followed this process.